# Is there a Class generator for data classes used in Java/Android from an existing wsdl file?

Tags: java, android, web-services, wsdl

Is there any class generators to process web services in Android/Java? I may have to write my own to generate classes against WSDL but I'm trying not to. Also is there one for REST services as well?

If not providing me with discovery service suggestions like disco/wsdl are good enough.

Answer (score -1):

Check WSDL2java.

http://ws.apache.org/axis2/tools/1_0/eclipse/wsdl2java-plugin.html

Comment: axis relies on java classes that are not supported on android.